# perl one liner + how to replace any last IP address octets

Tags: linux, sed, solaris, perl, ksh

How to replace any last IP address octets (four octet ) to 0

remark: Implementation should be by Perl one linear on linux machines

for example

```
      192.9.200.124 will replaced to 192.9.200.0
```

full example:

IP address before change:

```
  more file

  10.140.4.10 10.140.4.10 
  192.9.201  192.9.201 
  44.44.44 44.44.44
  100.100.1  100.100.1
  10.140.4.11 10.140.4.11
  45.0.0  45.0.0
  10.219.39.188 10.219.39.188
  10.219.39.189 10.219.39.189
  10.140.4.12  10.140.4.12
  10.219.39.138 10.219.39.138 
  10.219.39.139 10.219.39.139
```

Expected results (IP address after changing)

```
 more file

 10.140.4.0  10.140.4.0
 192.9.201  192.9.201 
 44.44.44 44.44.44 
 100.100.1  100.100.1 
 10.140.4.0 10.140.4.0
 45.0.0 45.0.0 
 10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0 
 10.219.39.0  10.219.39.0
 10.140.4.0 10.140.4.0 
 10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0 
 10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0
```

Comment: Why do you need a Perl one-liner?

Comment: because I need to run it also on solaris and solaris not support the "-i" sed flag

Comment: @yael `-i` uses tempfiles internally, you can quite easily do it yourself. `sed ... file > file.new && mv file.new file`

Comment: yes but I dont want to create anew file

Comment: @yael Like I said `-i` *also* creates a new file. It is not really in-place, it uses temporary files to achieve that effect.

Comment: yes - as I said I dont want to create any temp file - this is the reason that I want to use the perl ( to support linux and solaris )

Comment: @yael I'm not sure what you're not understanding here. `-i` in *both Perl and sed* creates temporary file(s), they do not do true in-place replacement. Using Perl will not avoid using a temporary file. You should always use a temporary file, you risk total data loss otherwise.

Comment: please see my remark , sed isnt exactly fit for both OS - linux and solaris , this is the reason that I want perl and not sed !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP originally asked a different question. There are 2 solutions that follow answer both questions which are similar but slightly different.

#### First solution

This should do what you want:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+$/${1}0/' sample.txt
10.140.4.0
192.9.201
44.44.44
100.100.1
10.140.4.0
45.0.0
10.219.39.0
10.219.39.0
10.140.4.0
10.219.39.0
10.219.39.0
```

#### explanation

This bit `(\d{1,3}\.){3}` finds a sequence (3) of digits (1-3 digits in length) followed by a period. This value is then saved in a temporary variable ($1). The brackets around that string save it `(\d{1,3}\.){3}). This sequence is then only matched if it's followed by a 4th octet (the 2nd \d+). All of this is then replaced with the first sequence (saved to`$1`) followed by a zero.

#### sample file

This is the sample file that I used. The OP posted a file that included some trailing spaces etc. which won't allow the Perl one-liner to work without adding additional code, which didn't seem relevant.

```
# sample.txt
10.140.4.10
192.9.201
44.44.44
100.100.1
10.140.4.11
45.0.0
10.219.39.188
10.219.39.189
10.140.4.12
10.219.39.138
10.219.39.139
```

#### Second solution

```
$ perl -pe 's/^((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+\s+((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+/${1}0 ${3}0/'
10.140.4.0 10.140.4.0 
192.9.201  192.9.201 
44.44.44 44.44.44
100.100.1  100.100.1
10.140.4.0 10.140.4.0
45.0.0  45.0.0
10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0
10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0
10.140.4.0 10.140.4.0
10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0 
10.219.39.0 10.219.39.0
```

Comment: I try it but its not work as example: echo  192.9.200.12  23.12.4.100  | perl -pe 's/^((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+$/${1}0/'
192.9.200.12 23.12.4.100

Comment: It's meant to take the list of IPs from a file. It needs them to be separated by a '\n'.

Comment: perl -pe 's/^((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+$/${1}0/' file , its also not change the octets from file

Comment: `echo -e "192.9.200.12\n23.12.4.100" | perl -pe 's/^((\d{1,3}\.){3})\d+$/${1}0/'`

Comment: I took your sample file and ran that, does you sample file have other characters in it? Trailing spaces etc? Those matter.

Comment: I guess my file also have TAB and spaces but perl should ignore them

Comment: It won't just ignore them. They're characters just like everything else. You have to provide code to just ignore them.

Comment: must be way to ignore the spaces inside the perl syntax

Comment: There always is, but you need to provide this in your question. You need to provide us with exactly what you're working with. Is the file as you've posted the real input file? Some lines have no extra spaces after them, while others have 2 trailing spaces. Most programming languages (Perl included) are going to care about these extraneous characters, it's not just going to ignore them! I think you should remove these as they over complicate the solution for no reason.

Comment: ok I update my question , please see  my update - thx

Comment: What is this? This isn't even the same problem anymore. Ugh! I don't understand why you didn't just post this to start with.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+\.){3}\K\d+/0/g' file
```

The `\K` works like a look-behind assertion, but it allows variable-length patterns.

Comment: echo 1.1.1.1 | perl -i -pe 's/(\d+\.){3}\K\d+/0/g' 1.1.1.1 ( not work )

Comment: You're passing stdin and also specifying a file name that probably doesn't exist (Do you have a file named "1.1.1.1"?) -- I get `echo 1.1.1.1 | perl -pe 's/(\d+\.){3}\K\d+/0/g'` ->
`1.1.1.0` -- this is perl v5.16.3, I'm not sure when `\K` was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sed` is in your tags, here is a `sed` answer:

```
sed '/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/s/\.[0-9]\+$/.0/'
```

Comment: your syntax not fit solaris -  echo 23.23.1.123 | sed '/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/s/\.[0-9]\+$/.0/' , its not change the last octets

Comment: is it possible to change your syntax to support also Solaris machines?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
perl -lpe 's/\d+$/0/' filename
```

You should append a blank line at the end of file.

Comment: @Gnoue little remark in case the file has two diff IP's as example echo  192.9.200.12  23.12.4.100  | perl -lpe 's/\d+$/0/'  , then your syntax change only the octets on the second IP , so how to change the last octets on both IP's ?

Comment: you must separate two IPs in two lines.

Comment: I cant my file have two IP's on both line

Comment: is it possible your syntax in way to replace the octets on both IP's on the same line?

Comment: This approach will not work if you want to leave the lines with 3 octets, but only change the lines with 4 octets!!!

Comment: @slm: it works with 3 octets.

Comment: The OP didn't want the lines with 3 octets to be changed. At least that was what the original file was showing in the results. For example with your approach you have line "192.9.201" the code you provided would change that line to "192.9.0", according to the example he wanted that left alone.

Comment: Add one space charector at the end of line, then it will works.